# Which probability distribution a generator in Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) is capturing: dataset or ground truth?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, probability, probability-distribution, generator

Consider the following statement from the abstract of the paper titled [Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2661.pdf)

> We propose a new framework for estimating generative models via an
> adversarial process, in which we simultaneously train two models: a
> generative model $G$ that **captures the data distribution**, and a
> discriminative model $D$ that estimates the probability that a sample
> came from the training data rather than $G$.

Let $D'$ be a dataset of $n$ digital and discrete* images, each of size $C \times H \times W$. Suppose the generative adversarial network is trained on the dataset $D'$.

Our sample space (or data set) is $D' = \{I_1, I_2, I_3, \cdots, I_n\}$, where $I_j$ is the $j^{th}$ image for $1 \le j \le n$

The random variables are $X_1, X_2, X_3, \cdots, X_{CHW}$ where

$$X_i \in \{a, a+1, a+2, \cdots, b\} =\text{ intensity of }i^{th} \text{ pixel;} \text{     for  } 1 \le i \le CHW$$

Since we have dataset $D'$, we can calculate the joint distribution $p_{data\_set}$ having $(b-a+1)^{CHW}$ parameters calculated from the dataset. But the parameters of the original image distribution $p_{ground_{D^{'}}} $is not equal to the $p_{D'}$

---

**Simple example:**

Suppose I flipped an unbiased coin 100 times and I got 45 heads, 55 tails, then $P_{data\_set}(H) = \dfrac{45}{100}$ and $P_{data\_set}(T) = \dfrac{55}{100}$. So,  $P_{data\_set} = \{\dfrac{45}{100}, \dfrac{55}{100}\}$

but the ground truth probability distribution is $P_{ground}(H) = \dfrac{50}{100}$ and $P_{ground}(T) = \dfrac{50}{100}$.  So,  $P_{ground} = \{\dfrac{50}{100}, \dfrac{50}{100}\}$

---

Which distribution is our generator capturing by the end? **Is it the probability distribution calculated based on our dataset $p_{data\_set}$ of images or the actual probability distribution $p_{ground}$?**

How to understand the **act of capturing** here? Does it only mean to be behaving (generating instances) in the same way as data distribution?

---

Suppose I design a machine that is capable to generate equal number of $0$'a as equal number of $1$'s for sufficiently large trails, then I can say that my machine captured the coin toss probability distribution?

---

- discrete images refers to the images whose pixel values takes finite number of integer values.